# Как изменить размер Callback кнопок в Telegram bot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Я пишу телеграмм бота на C#, использую библиотеку Telegram.Bot. Когда на Callback кнопке очень много текста он не помещается на нее и телеграмм автоматически дописывает "...".

Есть ли способ изменить размер кнопки, чтобы весь текст помещался на нее или сделать так, чтобы текст автоматически прокручивался по кнопке?

```
   if(ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "callback1") {
    var keyboard = new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardMarkup(
       new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButton[][]
            {
              new [] {
                     // First column
                     new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButton("Button 
                          text","callback2"),
                     },                                                                                           
              new [] { 
                     new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                     "Thi is exampl. example example example.A lot of text 
                     that does not fit on the button","callback3"),
                     },
             }
          );
     await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Message text", false, 
         false, 0, keyboard, Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode.Default);
     }
```

Вот как это выглядит:

[image: Вот как это выглядит.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, в текущей версии бот апи не реализован перенос строк и тп. Да оно и логично с точки зрения UX/UI - как будут выглядеть разнокалиберные кнопки или каково будет пользователю пытаться прокрутить текст в кнопке на 4 дюймовом экране? Просто мука для эстета и перфекциониста. Бот апи не может служить абсолютной заменой мобильным приложениям по понятным причинам - возможности не те.

---

**Выход есть, точнее - их даже два:**

**1. Используйте лаконичные надписи, тестируйте на разных устройствах.**
 *То, что не годится для 5 дюймов, прекрасно подходит для десктопа и наоборот*

**2. Если надпись невозможно уместить в требуемый размер - используйте разъясняющие сообщения.**
*Можно предварять поясняющим сообщением непосредственно сообщение, с той самой инлайн-кнопкой, на которой, в свою очередь, за счёт того, что пояснение уже было, надпись можно выводить упрощённо. Например - поясняющее сообщение - `Предлагаем Вам выбрать грибы. К съедобным грибам относятся .... К несъедобным относятся ...` Далее сообщение с инлайн-кнопками - `Ознакомьтесь с нашим ассортиментом` <kbd>Выбрать съедобные</kbd> <kbd>Выбрать несъедобные</kbd>*